24.04 - Raspberry Pi 5 with RP 7 Inch Screen Will Not Turn Off Screen When Blanking
I have a Raspberry Pi 5 with the Raspberry Pi 7 inch touchscreen. When I turn on screen blanking with Ubuntu 24.04 and it blanks, the screen changes but the screen does not turn off. Basically, the screen starts fading, but then turns a light gray and does not turn off the power. The same is true when I power off the device. The devices shuts down, but the screen does not turn off and just has the gray screen.

I have a separate microSD card with Raspbian bookworm on it and when I boot the device with that microSD card, everything works as expected. The blank screen is completely turned off and when I power off the device, the screen also turns off.
Do you have any suggestions for how to turn off the screen on Ubuntu 24.04?  I'm a fairly new Linux Ubuntu user so I could be wrong, but this seems unique to Ubuntu and the Raspberry Pi 5 and Raspberry Pi 7 inch screen.
I have tried:

xset dpms force off -> and also different forms of this to turn off the screen, but I get different errors.

xrandr --output DSI-1 --off -> DSI-1 is returned from --listmonitors and that too outputs some error about invalid parameter.

adding hdmi_blanking=1 to the boot config.txt -> It didn't help.


